# How to access JSON information given one information, if the other is a 'sibling' to that one, rather than a child, in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON/dictionary object in Python that looks like the following:

```
object = {"participants":
    [
        {"name": "Tyler", "role": "CEO"},
        {"name": "Robin", "role": "analyst"}
        {"name": "James", "role": "manager"}
    ]
}
```

Given a persons name, how do I access their role? As the role is not a "sub-information" of the name, you can't just do something like

```
object['participants']['Tyler']['role']
```

or something. You don't know the index of the specific person either (I presume you *can* make a loop that finds it if that is the only solution), so you can't just do

```
object['participants'][0]['role']
```

either, just because Tyler here happens to be at index 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
def jobs_where_name_is(json_object, name):
    return {entry["role"] for entry in filter(lambda entry: entry["name"] == name, json_object["participants"])}
```

Note that there might be more then one person with the same name, that's why a set of jobs is returned and not just one. There might be more than one person with the same name that work in the same job, so that's why I used curly brackets (set) instead of square brackets (list). Note that object is a keyword in python, so it is discouraged to use it as a variable name.

By the way, if you are working with a very large databse, I would recommend perhaps checking out the pymongo library. That could greatly improve your performance since you can use mongodb queries natively.

Comment: Thank you, and good idea. It worked. :D I don't actually use object as a variable name that was just for this post (I didn't know it was a keyword), but thanks for the tip anyway